# How to swap text in menu item back and forth?

Tags: menus, css, title, text

My article can be titled in two seemingly unrelated titles. Therefore, having the title swapping back and forth would be a cool feature. I suppose the effect would be crossfaded. The duration of the effect is 1 second, and the time between between two swapping events is 5 seconds. The result would look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in menu items? Also, here are some optional tasks:

- Having the title to swap in widgets or the article itself as well (I suppose this is much harder and would require working with php)
- Having a loading bar at the bottom of the title, indicating that it is about to swap

<sup>[Also asked on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/cr34sn/how_to_swap_menu_item_back_and_forth/)</sup>

Comment: This would theoretically be possible using a looping CSS animation and the `:before` and `:after` pseudo "elements".

Comment: Yes. There is always a way. As to how, that's a whole other story.